# Set window.location.hash on ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, hash, window.location

i belive it is quite simple question.

I am making an ajax call with jquery and all that i want is to set custom hash after the call similar to this:

```
window.location.hash = '?url=http://www.sitename.com';
```

but it returns # symbol before that and i dont want it

```
www.mysitename.com/#?url=http://www.sitename.com
```

so basically how to remove that # symbol and attach a clean hash without it?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to set the hash without a hash? That is not possible. The hash is part of the hash, hence the word *hash* (actually it is the fragment identifier, but no one seems to care). (too much hashes here...)

Comment: as long as there are only too *many* hashes but not too much hashish.. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot. If you want to set a query string (the `?something=something` stuff) you have to set it (and by doing so cause a page reload) by changing `location.search` (only the query string) or `location.href` - nothing AJAXish/Web2.0ish ;)

The hash is the client-side part after the `#` sign and never sent to the server. It's purely meant to target page elements (for example a `<h2 id="something">` is targeted by the hash `#something`) and nowadays to keep state information in the URL so the back/forward buttons keep working in AJAX applications (even though that'll eventually be replaced with HTML5's pushState function).

If you still want to use the hash, please do so in a [google-compatible way](http://code.google.com/intl/de/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html). Basically it means you should use `#!something` in the hash where `something` could also be part of the real URL in a classical (non-AJAX) request.

Comment: Or use the HTML5 History API, allowing to change the URL without reloading. Do you work for GitHub, ThiefMaster?

Comment: No, I just liked the octocat. Oh, and i did mention the html5 history api (pushState())

Comment: Yes, it seems you really did. From that I follow that I should go to sleep now. And yes, octocat is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

The `hash` in a URL is, per [the MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties):

> the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.

Note that the `#` character (which I believe is called the "pound sign" in North America) is generally called the "hash".

You want to set `window.location.search` instead.  This is:

> the part of the URL that follows the ? symbol, including the ? symbol.

Note that this triggers a reload. If you don't want this, you *need* to use the `hash` property.